# How come derivable enums are not supported?

Tags: typescript

How can an enum that is a subset of another enum be created?

It would be convenient in some scenarios to support an enum that is a subset of another Enum under a different name, that derives same values at run time.

Is there a better way to support this scenario?

TypeScript

```js
enum Original {
    value = "value",
    other = "other"
}

enum Derived {
    value = Original.value
}

const test: Original = Derived.value;
```

Generated JavaScript

```js
"use strict";
var Original;
(function (Original) {
    Original["value"] = "value";
    Original["other"] = "other";
})(Original || (Original = {}));
var Derived;
(function (Derived) {
    Derived["value"] = "value";
})(Derived || (Derived = {}));
const test = Derived.value;
```

It would be convenient if instead of assigning the static constant to the Derived enum the value was derived off of Original at run time.

Possibilities:

- Replacement: since the enum is derived off of an existing enum, compilation can replace the Derived values with the Original values. i.e. there is no need to create a separate Derived object in the JavaScript.

Example Replacement:

```js
"use strict";
var Original;
(function (Original) {
    Original["value"] = "value";
    Original["other"] = "other";
})(Original || (Original = {}));

const test = Original.value;
```

Comment: "*if instead of assigning the static constant to the Derived enum the value was derived off of Original at run time*" why would that make a difference? The enums wouldn't and *shouldn't* change at runtime, so whether you do `value = Original.value` or `value = "value"` that would not change how your code behaves.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this seems to be by defining a subtype of the `enum` using a union:

```js
enum Original {
    foo = "foo",
    bar = "bar",
    baz = "baz",
}

type Derived = Original.foo | Original.bar;
```

This doesn't allow you to write `Derived.foo`. If that's necessary, you could write a helper function to create objects representing enum subtypes:

```js
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

function enumSubtype<T, K extends keyof T>(e: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
    const out = {} as Pick<T, K>;
    for (let k of keys) {
        out[k] = e[k];
    }
    return out;
}

const Derived = enumSubtype(Original, ['foo', 'bar']);
type Derived = ValueOf<typeof Derived>;
```

The type `Derived` is `Original.foo | Original.bar`.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gTgSwOYJAQwDZQN4CgoFQBmA9iVALxQBEpJ1ANPoQEZpyU1tyPMFsAvTtUG8AvrkkAXAJ4AHYFABqmMMBhEAPABUAfJ20BtANbAZJIlG0BdANySiYEAGMpCEiCihIAZTAtZBR0GKABpLwAPKVAAEwBnKFNzSz0ACmAALisQpLis0MNrAEosgAUEZ2NgsP08QihnDzipKBIwFqpsMSg0BPLK6tDde3rSDlSMYBbjVstcopw+etb2k2tOYDWRwgl6uCmwOE82qXsJXEaQZqgAEWBEADdgGI3wCD8A+WBU+GRUTBChgA5HQgSEgdwgcV7IFFHdHs9OCoMGoNJpYRZbvcEE8YsNcEA)

Comment: you were correct, thanks. a type union is definitely the better approach.